# Question about entanglement

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics, quantum-entanglement

(There are a lot of questions about entanglement shown in the Similar Questions box. If there's already something about what I'm about to ask, please refer me there.)

Suppose the particle paths are arranged to be of different length (e.g., detector A is close to the emitter but detector B is many miles away). And suppose that both detectors provide an exact time stamp of the detection event. Upon reading the logs of the two detectors, would you find that both detections registered at the same time, indicating that one particle got "stuck" in detector A until the other particle was detected at B?

Comment: So the system at $A$ somehow instantly knows what happens at $B$?  I'm sure you can find a geeat many posts on this site explaining why information can't travel faster than light.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I thought it was well established that there is no experimental evidence that the proposition that information (by itself) is traveling too fast has any warrant to prevent an undisturbed operation from occurring.

Comment: Asking "will the coincidence detector  falsely claim that the arrival times are equal?" is like asking "will the coincidence detector falsely claim that the particle is a giraffe?".   There is no remotely plausible reason to expect such a thing, which means that if this question counted as on-topic, then so would eight billion other equally unmotivated questions about what a particle detector might falsely claim.

Answer (score 1):

In a typical experiment where measurements are made on entangled photons, the source of entangled photon pairs would produce several pairs in sequence to build up statistics. The photons are detected with sensitive detectors, such a avalanche photo diodes that produce electrical pulses for the individually detected photons which are then sent to a coincidence counter. Modern coincidence counters, which are used to register the measurements of quantum correlations, keep precise time stamps (typically with nano second resolution) of the arrival times of the photons that are detected. So, if the paths are different, a correlation can still be determined between the sequences of detections at the respective detectors. So, even though the photons is destroyed the moment it is detected, the information of its arrival time is stored so that any quantum correlations can be determined.

Comment: I'm asking what happens if the detectors are arranged so there's more than just a few nanoseconds between the theoretical arrival times. Would the coincidence detector falsely claim that the arrival times are still equal? And if an orientation was changed between the two arrivals, would the statistics indicate the earlier or the later setting?

Comment: If the path lengths are sufficiently different the detectors will sense the photons at different times and the coincidence detector would find no coincidence. That is, the arrival times of the photons at the detectors are different. This is not to say they are uncorrelated. As flippiefanus states, the detection times can be recorded and correlations between measurements determined. So if one detector is 300,000 km further away than the other, there will be highly correlated detections of entangled photons at times typically 1 second apart (since light travels 300,000 km in a second).